Unity Asset Rendering Distance
So I have some low poly assets I am struggling to get rendered in the distance. They appear Dark Blue. As you can see, the ones closer, render correctly. They only render in the correct color the moment I get close in my "free look" camera (Before pressing play) and my First person controller approaching the asset in "Play Mode".
I tried changing the "Clipping planes Far" on my terrain. Had a look around unity documentation and YouTube. I just cant find anyone that was experiencing the same. I tried adding a LOD layer also to the terrain and playing with the values, it just doesn't render anything in the distance. Can you advise a direction I can run into?


Could this be some weird fog setting?

In Terrain Inspector, open the last tab and play with Billboard Start. If the border between blue and normal trees changes, the problem is billboard generation. If this is true, you can fix the issue either by changing the Billboard Start, Tree Distance, Fade Length & Max Mesh Trees Terrain settings so no billboards are generated. Or by fixing the shader compatibility with billboard generation process (maybe just try the foliage shader). Performance wise both options can be valid, requires testing. E.g. on mobile poly trees can even be faster than billboards due to no transparency.

Thank you so much. You led me to the exact property I needed. It was indeed "Billboard Start". I changed the tree distance, detail distance but never changed the billboard start and that revealed the trees in the distance as I increased the value. Please post as as response so I can mark it as the answer.
